# Nested Casting using Class.cast() Method

Tags: java, class, casting, clone

I have a `Person` class, which implements `Cloneable`. I then have Objects `p` and `o` which reference a `Person` object. I am trying to clone one into another, and discovered that the following works:

```
Object p = new Person("Heather");
Object o = ((Person)p).clone();
```

(I have to use that cast because `clone()` is protected in Object. I use this to call `clone()` in `Person` instead.)

What I need to know is how to perform the above cast using `Class.cast()`. I know how to cast once, it would be something like this:

```
Object o = p.getClass().cast(p);
```

But how do I do the nested casting example in this way. (I need to know because in this project, I won't always know what class to cast to but I WILL know the class is `Cloneable`.)

I tried…
    ((Cloneable)p).clone()
...but that doesn't work. The clone() method is a protected method in the Object class, and interface Cloneable does not have a clone() method, so the compiler can't recognize it.

I've looked all over for an answer and can't find one anywhere. Thank you for your help.

Comment: If you know they will all be Cloneable types, and you just want to clone them, I don't see why you couldn't you get away with Object o = ((Cloneable)p).clone();. Polymorphism FTW!

Comment: All Class.cast does is perform a cast check operation on the object, to make sure it's an instance of that class.  It then leaves it to the compiler (which will likely perform ANOTHER cast check) to do its generic tap dance.

Comment: Sad to say ((Cloneable)p).clone() didn't work. clone() is a protected method on Object, it is not in the interface Cloneable, so the compiler doesn't recognize it. Any other ideas?

Comment: Maybe wrap `Cloneable` with your own interface which supports the `clone()` method?

Comment: What do you mean by "nested casting"???

Comment: By nested casting, I mean that there are two parenthesis pairs instead of just 1. ((Cloneable).p).clone() instead of, for example, (int) 3.2. Is wrapping a better word?

Comment: @webuster I'll keep experimenting, but do you mean something like (((Cloneable)MyOwnInterface)p).clone()?

Comment: I meant just `((YourInterface)p).clone()`, where your interface extends Cloneable and still exposes the clone() method.

Comment: Your idea works as long as I implement the interface onto any Cloneable class that I write. It doesn't work, however, for built-in java classes. - I'll see if I can work with this but feel free to keep the ideas coming. (And thank you.)

Comment: Parentheses (other than the ones immediately surrounding the class name) have no effect on cast operations other than to establish evaluation order.  `((YourInterface)p).clone()` means exactly the same as `YourInterface temp = (YourInterface)p; temp.clone()`.

Comment: "By convention, classes that implement this interface (Cloneable) should override Object.clone (which is protected) with a public method. See Object.clone() for details on overriding this method."  No game you play with casts is going to get around this point.

Comment: I appreciate the intel. I'll work on seeing if I can use it in my project and post something here. Probably within the next day or two.

Answer (score 1):

Using `clone()` is unusual in code (I have never used it nor seen it used explicitly like that).

The usual pattern to use for making copies is the [*copy constructor*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Copy_constructor), eg:

```
public class Person {
    private String name;
    public Person(String name) {
       this.name = name;
    }

    // Copy constructor
    public Person(Person person) {
        this(person.name);
    }
}
```

Values of the important fields of the source object are used to initialize field values of the new object.

Answer (score 0):

This is kind of a difficult thing because of the way clone works. As you noticed, pretty much clone is a protected method so you need a class at compile time to call it. There's one way around this which is to declare an interface that assigns it public access:

```
public interface PublicCloneable
extends Cloneable {
    public Object clone();
}
```

Then implement that instead of Cloneable. Then you are able to cast to PublicCloneable to call clone. This will work OK but it still carries with it all the normal problems with clone.

Creating a copy constructor is a great alternative to clone and you can make a method to call it with reflection if you don't know the class at compile time:

```
static Object reflectionCopy(Object obj) {
    try {
        Class<?> cls = obj.getClass();
        Constructor<?> ctor = cls.getConstructor(cls);
        return ctor.newInstance(obj);
    } catch(Exception e) {
        return obj;
    }
}
```

(`getClass` always returns a `Class<?>` so that can also be made generic if you don't mind an unchecked cast.)

Probably what you are running in to here is an indication you need to think about your design. Personally this sounds to me like a case where a generic factory could be advantageous.

Basically something like this:

```
public interface Copier<T> {
    public T createCopy(T obj);
}

public class PersonCopier
implements Copier<Person> {
    @Override
    public Person createCopy(Person person) {
        return new Person(person.getName());
    }
}

public static <T> T doStuffInvolvingCopy(T inObject, Copier<T> copier) {
    ...

    T copy = copier.createCopy(inObject);

    ...

    return copy;
}
```

You might call that like

```
doStuffInvolvingCopy(new Person("Heather"), new PersonCopier());
```

or perhaps keep the factories registered somewhere so they do not need to be passed around.

Factories are good because they don't use clone and don't use reflection.